# In which directory or filepath are you supposed to run eval ssh-agent?

Tags: git, ubuntu, github, ssh-keys, ssh-agent

I'm building out a couple git users on my PC(ubuntu) to practice workflow on Github and was using this [website](http://hmkcode.com/git-tutorial/how-to--with-multiple-github-accounts-on-one-computer/) to build out the users. I'm at the 3rd part and just typed in `eval '$(ssh-agent)'` but get back

```
bash: SSH_AUTH_SOCK=/tmp/ssh-FxjmM29tR2ak/agent.3856;: No such file or directory
```

`Is there a way to solve this?

Comment: have you tried the usual way, `eval \`ssh-agent\``?

Answer (score 5):

There should not be single quotes in that command. Like this:

```
eval $(ssh-agent)
```

> Which directory or filepath are you suppose to run eval ssh-agent in?

The problem had nothing to do with the directory in which you run the command.

The problem is that you evaluated the literal string '$(ssh-agent)', instead of the output of that command. The single quotes make the difference.

Comment: The `$(...)` runs the command inside the parentheses in a sub-shell